# Injecting default "management.endpoints.web.base-path" value in Spring Boot 2.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to inject "management.endpoints.web.base-path" into my class's field that I need to know. I did a few hours of search for it, but all the answer is "how to customize your endpoint" by setting management.endpoints.web.base-path in the application.xml(or yaml), not "how to get a default of management.endpoints.web.base-path".

Simple code as below was expecting to grab whatever variable loaded when Spring Boot app is starting up, but nothing was retrieved in the variable.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public void myMethod(){
    final String actuatorBase = environment.getProperty("management.endpoints.web.base-path");
}
```

If I define it in the application.properties I should be able to load it for sure, but I'd like to know why the default("/actuator") can't be retrieved here. However when I run the application, I had no problem to access all the actuator related functionality endpoint through /actuator.

Since it doesn't work, injecting the variable with @Value annotation also doesn't work either.

When I checked the environment variable in the debugger, I was able to see application.yaml is loaded and all the overrides variables are there, too, but not all the default "management" stuff was there.

Any idea? This app has some custom configuration, not using all the AutoConfigurer stuff, so wondering if there is specific autoconfig I need to use to make it happen.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answering here.

WebEndpointProperties is the one that loads all the management.endpoints.web prefix properties, so simply

```
@Autowired
private WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties;
```

in the class and then

```
String actuatorWebBasePath = this.webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
```

in my method gave me a base path(/actuator).